# Como puedo resolver este problema de menu usando listas y al final imprima en formato json

Tags: python, json, lambda

Tengo esta actividad para la escuela pero al momento de correr el programa solo me responde la primera pregunta y después sale del programa. El chiste o proposito de este problema es crear un menú de figuras en el que las preguntas se vinculen con las respuestas y me mande con otra pregunta dentro de la lista de preguntas con las respuestas encaso de de que el menu se agreguen mas opciones y que al final se guarde en un archivo `json`.

```
print("\n","****************BIENVENIDO AL MENU DE FIGURAS**************")
LPreguntas = [
      [
        1,"¿Cuantos lados tiene tu figura?",
        "a) 0  b) 3  c) 4 \n"
    ],
    [
        2,"¿Radio Constante?",
        "d) si   e) no \n"
    ],
    [3,"Circulo"],
    [4,"elipse"]
]
LRespuestas = [
    ["a",2],
    ["d",3],
    ["e",4]
]

PreguntaActiva = 1

#Buscar pregunta
Dato1 = filter(lambda e: e[0] == PreguntaActiva,LPreguntas)
LDato = list(Dato)[0]
print("\n","Pregunta:", LDato1[1])
Resp = input(LDato1[2])

Dato = filter(lambda e: e[0] == Resp,LRespuestas)
LDato = list(Dato)[0]
PreguntaActiva = LDato[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

El modelamiento de datos deja que desear. Una alternativa es definir la pregunta como una tupla compuesta de:

- Texto de la pregunta.
- Lista de alternativas.
- Alternativa correcta.

Con eso dejo todo en un solo lugar y no tengo que manejar listas paralelas.

```
print("\n","****************BIENVENIDO AL MENU DE FIGURAS**************")
LPreguntas = [
    ("¿Cuantos lados tiene tu figura?", [0, 3, 4], 2),
    ("¿Radio Constante?", ['si', 'no'], 0)
    ]

for pregunta in LPreguntas:
    print(pregunta[0])

    for alt in range(len(pregunta[1])):
        texto = pregunta[1][alt]
        print(f"{alt + 1}) {texto}.")

    eleccion = int(input("Ingrese alteranativa: ")) - 1
    if eleccion == pregunta[2]:
        print("Correcto")
    else:
        print("Error")
```

El código recorre la lista de pregunta, presenta el texto y luego coloca las alternativas, una por línea.

La opción elegida por el usuario es comparada con la opción registrada en la pregunta, y se emite un mensaje acorde.

#### Demo

```
 ****************BIENVENIDO AL MENU DE FIGURAS**************
¿Cuantos lados tiene tu figura?
1) 0.
2) 3.
3) 4.
Ingrese alteranativa: 3
Correcto
¿Radio Constante?
1) si.
2) no.
Ingrese alteranativa: 2
Error

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: No está mal ese proceso del Código aunque el objetivo del programa es que de la primera respuesta de la figura me mande a la siguiente usando la otra lista que contiene las respuestas vinculadas a los números de las preguntas y de esta forma que mande a una siguiente en caso de que se aumenten las preguntas. ¿si me explico?